# Probability of drawing 2 sets of triplets plus one pair from a poker deck.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, poker

If I consider a poker deck with $13$ ranks of $4$ cards each, what is the probability of obtaining 2 triplets and 1 pair (eg. AAA77733) in the following two scenarios:

- (A) when drawing 8 cards?
- (B) when drawing 16 cards?

(In the 16-card case, I want two ranks with at least 3 cards each, and a third rank with at least 2 cards.)  My approach using combinatorics for (A) is: Choose 3 ranks out of 13 and 3 cards out of 4 each for 2 ranks and 2 cards out of 4 for the third rank, then divide by the total number of combinations of 8 cards:

$$
\frac{{{13}\choose{3}} \cdot {{4}\choose{3}}^2 \cdot {{4}\choose{2}}}{{{52}\choose{8}}}
= \frac{27456}{752538150},
$$
or about $1$ in $27409$.

Is this correct?

By what factor do I have to multiply the probability in (A) in order to get the probability in (B)?

Comment: For (A) you need also to choose which rank is the pair.

Comment: For (B), are you discarding whichever 8 cards you choose?  Or discarding 8 cards at random?  If it's the latter, then the probability is the same as in (A)... the extra draw and discard makes no difference to the fact that, in then end, you have a hand of 8 cards chosen uniformly at random from all possible 8-card hands.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMathias. Which means the numerator becomes 13C2 x (4C3)^2 x 11C1 x 4C2 which increases it by a factor of 3? It seems correct but I don’t understand why the pair has to be singled out.

Comment: The pair is not being singled out. You could also choose two ranks for the triples and a third rank for the pair. The important thing is that you need to determine which ranks are triples and which rank is pair.

Comment: Thanks @mjqxxxx for your interesting and valid point. In that case, I should not have said discard. What I want is at least 2 sets of triplets plus 1 pair in the 16 cards drawn. If I have that, the other 8 cards will not matter. Is this the same as saying I choose the discards?

Comment: Thanks @DanielMathias. I think I am getting it. As long as the sets are different, I have to consider them separately?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's the same as saying you choose the discards.  Alternately, it's the same as asking for the probability that you have two ranks with at least triplets and one rank with at least a pair in a 16-card hand.

Comment: @mjqxxxx If I extend my numerator to a 16-card hand and want the same outcome, I would formulate it as (13C2x(4C3)^2) x (11C1x4C2) x (44C8) since the extra 8 cards can be any cards from the remaining 44. And when I divide it by 52C16 possible 16-card combinations, I get 1.4087. I am lost. It seems there is a divisor I am missing.

Comment: That approach is not going to work, because you're overcounting: there are many cases where multiple choices of the 8 cards to keep meet your criteria, e.g., AAA7733KKK8844, or AAAAKKKK77775432.  In fact, the problem with 16 cards is not that straightforward.

Comment: Here's one general way to handle this.  Let $p_{a,b,c}(n)$ be the probability, after drawing $n$ cards, that you have all four cards for $a$ ranks, exactly three cards for $b$ ranks, and exactly two cards for $c$ ranks.  You should be able to calculate this probability for arbitrary $(a,b,c)$.  For your problem, you're asking about the probability that $a+b \ge 2$ and $a+b+c \ge 3$; so just sum $p_{a,b,c}(n)$ over all $(a,b,c)$ satisfying those constraints.

Comment: Thanks, @mjqxxxx. In general, I’m trying to get the probability of an event E of certain combination of r cards when drawing k cards from a deck of n cards. Not restricted to three cards of x ranks plus two of y ranks for example. I am able to calculate the probabilities of the events I want using combinatorics when k = r. When k > r, there is overcounting, as you say. I postulate the overcounting to be by a factor f. I theorize the general equation to be count(E)*(n-r)C(k-r)/nCk/f. This is equivalent to count(E)*kCr/nCr/f.

Comment: In my example in (A), count(E) works out to 82368, k = r and f = 1, i.e. no overcounting. When k = n, P(E) should be 1, so f would be 82368 meaning E is overcounted by 1 time over. I’m hoping to derive this factor f, if it’s at all possible. 

I’m afraid I don’t quite understand how to calculate the probabilities the way you suggested. Also wonder whether it would get unyielding when k gets large.